# Polish letters 'ą' and 'ę' encoding

Tags: macros, font-encodings

I have a strange problem with font encoding(?).
`pdflatex` changes the Polish letters 'ą' and 'ę' to '1.39a' or '1.39e'.

I use the following packages:

```
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

I did not modify (no updates, no new installations) my LaTeX distribution (TeXlive), but a few days earlier everything was fine. What is going on?

Comment: You need to have a font that supports them too.  Try `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Comment: It didn't work. I'm sure, I have everything what I need to write in polish, because I use this preamble since year and it's worked. Until now :/

Comment: If you compile a document with just those packages and the two characters 'ą' and 'ę', does it not work?  Do you get any warnings in the log?  If so, report them back here.

Comment: There is no warnings... Here's log file: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3837977/document.log

Comment: That's not the log from the minimal document.  If you want to figure this out, you're going to have to add packages one by one back into the minimal document to see if one of them is causing the problem.

Comment: I would change the loading order: (1) fontenc; (2) inputenc; (3) polski

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you need to use QX font encoding, not T1, if you want hyphenation & other details to work properly.

Answer (score 15):

Don't redefine the command `\k` (probably you are using it in some picture code).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
^^c4^^85 %ascii-alias for a with ogonek

\def\k{1.39} ^^c4^^85

\end{document}
```

And next time: Don't post code snippets. Make a complete minimal example. It is simply inconsiderate to waste other peoples time and let them guess around when your code could *show* the source of the problem.

Comment: I definitely agree with you that the OP should post a complete minimal example, but the fact that polski relies on a working `\k` seems a bug of its own. The purpose of the `\makeatletter` trick is exactly to avoid this kind of problems, so packages should use it whenever possible.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: \k is a kernel command for the "accent" ogonek. It is similar to `\c` or `\d` or `\"`. It is fontenc (the OT4 encoding) which relies on it and it is dangerous to redefine such commands. The OP is probably doing it by using `\k` in a `\foreach` loop. `\makeatletter` has nothing to do with it and `polski` is not at fault (at least as far as I can see from the few informations the OP provided).

Comment: This has nothing to do with `polski.sty`, which uses `\k` normally. The problem is that the OP probably used `\def` instead of `\newcommand` and overwrote the definition of `\k`. (Or as Ulrike just said, somewhere within a `\foreach` loop.)